# Execute .exe with drag and drop with a script

Tags: vba, shell

is there a way to execute a .exe with dragging a file on it in a script?

it should work the same way as i do it manually

take file -> drop it on .exe -> exe should be started with this file

Would prefer a VB Script

that's what i tried so far:

```
objShell.ShellExecute "xyz.exe", "xyz.file", "", "open", 1
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShellExecute is the correct way, however usually Windows when drag and drop into a script or executable sends the dropped file as command line argument. So instead xyz.exe it should be:

```
WScript.Arguments(0)
```

Comment: you mean like this? (objShell.ShellExecute "WScript.Arguments(0)", "xyz.file", "", "open", 1)  but how does my script then know which .exe he should drag the file on?

Comment: When you drag the exe file into the script the absolute path to the exe is passed as command-line argument to the script, so in the first index of the arguments there is the path to the exe to execute

Comment: yeah thats the point i want to "simulate" that drag and drop on the exe file by a script so i just double click the script and it automaticaly drag and drops a file onto the exe and starts it. and i cant figure out how to manage that

Comment: Oh sorry, I've misunderstood. So you have to ShellExecute on the target exe and pass as parameter the file you want to simulate the drag and drop with double-quotes ex: `chrome.exe "page.html"`